# How long does it take for my Prestige to update on my Player Card?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3, call-of-duty-world-at-war

I was playing *Call of Duty: World at War* yesterday and I reached 10th prestige.

However, on *Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3* and *Call of Duty: Black Ops*, my Player Card still shows the 9th prestige badge for *World at War*.

How long will it take for my Player Card in *Modern Warfare 3* and *Black Ops* to update to show the 10th prestige badge?

Comment: It's really hard to understand what you're asking here.  Please invest a bit of effort into making this more readable.

Comment: @Frank fixed it, he means when you highlight your player card or other users do and they can see your prestige level on other call of duty's

Comment: @Rainbows I don't think it means what you think it means, but I don't play CoD at all.  I'll let others decide if that's what he means or not.

Comment: @Frank it is trust me when he's talking about it updating, takes about 3 days for the Call of Duty servers to update it

Comment: Thanks @Rainbows and ya sry that was confusing. So t will be three days for the ranks to be updated.

Comment: @Rainbows it's been three days and it still has not changed.

Comment: @JTM ask their live support whats going on

Answer (score 2):

Both Infinity Ward and Treyarch refresh their servers regularly. As I stated in a comment, it can take up to 3 days to update.